# How to produce a set of Char from a set of String in Scala

Tags: scala, set, map-function

I want to create a set with the first character from a set of strings. Seems like I should be able to map easily but I can't figure out the correct syntax or find it on SO or the rest of the web. Here's where I'm at:

```
val mySetOfStrings = scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]()
def charSet: Set[Char] = mySetOfStrings.map[Char]((s: String) => s.head)

//IDE tells me "Expression of type Char doesn't conform to expected type B"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDE error isn't correct, but manually supplying type parameters to `map` is going to cause you problems, because the signature of `map` is really:

```
final def map[B, That](f: (A) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

So the actual compiler error is:

```
<console>:12: error: wrong number of type parameters for method map: [B, That](f: String => B)(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String],B,That])That
       strings.map[Char](_.head)
                  ^
```

Note that there are two type parameters, and not one. The compiler will infer `Char` on its own, though.

```
scala> val strings = Set("abc", "def", "ijk")

scala> strings.map(_.head)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(a, d, i)
```

Manually supplying the type parameters would have to look like this:

```
scala> strings.map[Char, Set[Char]](_.head)
res6: Set[Char] = Set(a, d, i)
```

Comment: Note that calling `head` is _not_ safe if any of the strings are empty. In which case you should use `flatMap(_.headOption)` to ignore them.

Comment: Accepted because you made me understand where I was going wrong. Appreciation to both the other (slightly) quicker answers too though.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> Set("foo", "bar", "baz").map( s => s.head )
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(f, b)
```

You usually don't supply the type arguments to the map method yourself.

Comment: `scala> Set("foo", "bar", "").map( s => s.head )
java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore empty strings in the input then you can use:

```
mySetOfStrings.flatMap(_.headOption)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to bypassing empty strings,

```
mySetOfStrings.flatMap(_.take(1))
```